# У меня возникла ошибка с модулем random

Tags: python, discord

Часть кода:

```
@Bot.command()
async def buy(ctx):
      text = None
      channel = Bot.get_channel(694249208936530012)
      random1 = random.randrange(1,8)
```

Ошибка:

```
File "Discord-Bot-Test-1.py", line 26
    random1 = random.randrange(1,8)
                                  ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: У вас смешаны табы и пробелы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас отступы в функции неправильные. Выровняйте:

```
async def buy(ctx):
    text = None
    channel = Bot.get_channel(694249208936530012)
    random1 = random.randrange(1,8)
```

Comment: спасибо что помого !!!

Comment: @StanislavDidus тыкни галочку напротив ответа